# possible to access an application in Websphere application server cluster without load balances or web server?

Tags: redirect, webserver, websphere, cluster-computing

I am trying setting up an websphere application server cluster and deploy an web application on it. I have successfully access the application with a web server. but i have some question, if i would access the application bypassing the web server by using 9080 to the single server, i get error when sign in servlet respond.redirect to jsp page. the session was lost, are we not suppose to access the application in cluster environment with out the web server ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you target an individual server in the cluster, you should not lose your session or suffer any other ill effects for not using/having a proxy server between you and the cluster.  You should look closely at the Cookies issued through that flow and make sure they don't have a bad domain or path and that you don't get redirected back through the webserver or otherwise to another JVM.

Also verify there is no DNS-based load balancing. If you don't have session persistence/distribution/replication it won't work.